# Issue with Google Maps JavaScript API and ionic 2

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ionic2

I'm having some troubles with the Google Maps JavaScript API used in my ionic 2 application. The first time I show the map on a page it will be rendered fine - [see first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXdL4.png). After navigating back and opening the page with the Google Map again the map won't be rendered correctly any more. I just get a grey area instead - [see second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ghrd.png).

I already searched for this issue, but nobody had a solution yet as far as I know ([thread with same topic here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/blank-google-maps-after-navigation/51104/10))

Maybe anyone else can help me out here?

I also created a [github repository](https://github.com/baumgarb/ionic-2-google-maps-issue) which can be cloned and fired up easily so that you can reproduce the issue. Pls note that ionic 2 should be up and running if you want to try this out.

Thanks in advance!

[image: works fine]
[image: doesnt work, just a grey area]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally found the workaround. Take a look at the post of *ddellamico* in [this thread](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/issues/212). You need to trigger the resize event on the google maps object everytime you **enter** the specific page. So place the following code in the **ionViewDidEnter()** event.

```
// this.map refers to the google maps object created via 'new google.maps.Map(...)'
google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize');
```

Make sure you use the ionViewDid**Enter**() event instead of the ionViewDid**Load**() event.

If you want the map to center at a specific point or marker again you should do the following additionally:

```
// Longitude and latitude are just examples
// Of course longitude and latide should refer to your specific point the map should center on
this.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(47.0712025, 15.4382784));
```

Comment: google.map.event.trigger()
where did u define this google

Comment: What's the code for the Ionic native google maps plugin?